# Purging the internal transmit buffer of FT201X I2C-Slave

Tags: c++, i2c, ftdi, d2xx

Im trying to purge the FX-Buffer of the FT201X I2C-Slave. Somehow it seems not to work, the master still reads old data sets even after the purge-function is called. Im using C++(Visual Studio 2019) with the D2XX-functions given in the D2XX-Programmers-Guide.

I did try to use the StopInTask and RestartInTask functions before and after the purge command, but it still does not clear my buffer.

```
status = FT_StopInTask(fthandle);
    if (status != FT_OK) {
        printf("status not ok %d\n", status);
    }
    status = FT_Purge(fthandle, FT_PURGE_TX); // Purge Tx buffer
    if (status != FT_OK) {
        printf("status not ok %d\n", status);
    }
    status = FT_RestartInTask(fthandle);
    if (status != FT_OK) {
        printf("status not ok %d\n", status);
    }
```

I did even try `FT_W32_PurgeComm(fthandle, PURGE_TXABORT | PURGE_TXCLEAR)`, the buffer still appears to not be cleared, even if the function returns true.

Comment: Playing with FT_SetLatency, FT_SetUSBParameters and FT_SetTimeouts seems to help, but i still cannot get the buffer purging consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow `FT_Purge(fthandle, FT_PURGE_RX)` clears both buffers, the buffer that stores the data coming from the host (sent via FT_Write) as well as the buffer that stores data coming from an external I2C-Master. Mapping the signal `RXF` (value: 10) to a CBUS-pin and reading the pins with `FT_GetBitMode` works to indicate if the buffer that stores data from the host is empty.